# how to find which process / service do criminal traffic via port 11413

Tags: linux, rhel, port-forwarding, netstat

we get message from our security department

about criminal traffic via port 11413 from linux machine A to linux machine B

please advice how to find who use this port and details about the traffic

from **netstat -a** we don't see the port 11413 is licensing

Comment: If your security department has not identified the details of the traffic, then it has insufficient basis for determining that it is "criminal"; if it knows what the traffic is and why it is "criminal", then _it can tell you what the traffic is_.  The people that you need to be asking questions of are the people in your security department, not really us out here in the rest of the world.  Start with "Is this TCP? Or UDP?" and progress on to "When did/do you observe it happening?" and "What have your packet captures told you about it?  What kind of thing am I supposed to be looking for?"

Comment: You could take a packet capture and look for the [evil bit](https://www.ietf.org/rfc/rfc3514.txt) being set.

Answer (score 1):

netstat might not be showing any details about 11413 because that port might not be in use at that time. You can ask network team to inform you whenever they see criminal traffic, so that you can check by executing

```
lsof -i :11413
```

Or

Create a simple script to run in loop with `sleep` command (for defining time interval) and execute command `lsof -i :11413` and write o/p to a file on successful execution.

Comment: hi - what the command lsof -i :11413 actually do?

Comment: It will list command,pid and owner details of app using port 11413.